# Conditional testing for existence of an element

Tags: jquery

I want to do this with jQuery

```
if $(".video-gallery-container") exists {
$(".video-gallery-container").fadeOut(300);
}
```

What's the proper way for checking for existence of an element with jQuery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an "exists" function for jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery)

Comment: You don't have to check whether element exists or not, jQuery doesn't throw error if element doesn't exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery provides the `.length` property for exactly this purpose:

```
if($(".video-gallery-container").length) {
    //.....
}
```

However, in your case you don't really need to worry about it: Just do the `fadeOut` without testing, because the `fadeOut` will only be applied to elements that match the selector; if there aren't any elements that match, the `fadeOut` won't be applied, but there won't be any errors.

Comment: Thank you, @Spudley – so, there's no need to do `.length>0` ? just `.length` is enough?

Comment: @KeithRules - just `.lenth` is sufficient because of the way javascript tests truthy values. But as I said, you don't even need to do that; the whole `if()` test isn't required at all in the example you've given.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to. If a selection is empty, any jQuery function called on it will simply fail to do anything:

```
$(".video-gallery-container").fadeOut(300);
```

That is all you need do.

Comment: What if I have it as a function: `$(".video-gallery-container").fadeOut(300, function() { // some code` - if there's bo video-gallery-container, I'm assuming it will prevent the inside code from being executed, no?

Comment: Yes. It's essentially a `for` loop. Think how many times `for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)` will run if `arr` is an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($(".video-gallery-container").length > 0){
  $(".video-gallery-container").fadeOut(300);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($(".video-gallery-container").length > 0){  
  $(".video-gallery-container").fadeOut(300); 
}
```

Also you need not check for existence. jQuery will only add fadeOut if the element exists, otherwise it will not do anything. no error will be produced.